# Can positive punishment occur when dreaming?

Tags: dreams, reinforcement-learning

If you dream of experiencing some behaviour involving positive punishment, can this behaviour reinforce itself in real life?

Comment: Punishment = Searches extintion of a behaviour. Reinforcement  = searches  promotion oof it. 

I think you're refering to Negative Reinforcement, when someone does something that you percieve as negative to only reinforce the behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn That last part is incorrect: Negative reinforcement = when someone **stops** doing something to reinforce behaviour (eg, if I stop electrocuting you when you do what I want).  The OP's original example was of positive punishment (eg, I make you feel bad when you stutter).  Positive punishment (when effective) reduces the behaviour.  The OP is asking if dreaming about punishment of the behaviour would reduce the behaviour while awake.

Comment: Yeah I understand the issue i got is more semantic, since he first states positive punishment but later asks if this behaviour will be reinforced while awake and punishment is contrary to reinforcement,and  hence the confusion.

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn I thought this was all negative reinforcement because when I was talking about the stutter, I said there is an increase in avoidance behaviours following on from exhibiting those avoidance behaviours in dreams, which surely is reinforcement?